# How to update Access Table fields only if linked table is not null

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am making an Access database of our SKU information, and it contains 58 columns of information. I'd like to pull out a report from our system and Update the database with the new information, or Append new records if I have set up new items.

I created a table called SKUP, and also linked a table to Excel called LINK_SKUP.
I have a query which pulls out any records from LINK_SKUP that have a modify date after the max date in the SKUP table (This query is called [NeedUpdateQ]), and an append query of items which are not already included in the SKUP table. These seem to be working correctly so far.

I'm trying to make the Update query, but sometimes I may not pull a FULL report of all 58 columns (because it isn't always necessary), so I wanted to add a step to the Update to only update the column if it is not null.

In the "Field", I typed:

```
SKU_DESC: IIF( ISNULL( [NeedUpdateQ].[SKU_DESC] ) , [SKUP].[SKU_DESC] , [NeedUpdateQ].[SKU_DESC] )
```

This worked properly when I tested it, so I added this same type of iif(isnull([NeedUpdateQ]),[SKUP],[NeedUpdateQ]) to every single column, then when I try to view the results now, it tells me this:

> " 'IIf(IsNull([NeedUpdateQ].[SKU_DESC]),[SKUP].[SKU_DESC],[NeedUpdateQ].[SKU_DESC])' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long."

I'm not sure on where this went wrong, as it was definitely showing me the results properly before (I tried making a few descriptions null to test, and it still showed the descriptions shown in SKUP), but now it doesn't seem to be working again.
Would anyone have any tips on how to fix this or possibly even a more efficient way of updating this?

Comment: Since you mention you added this same expression to *every single column*, carefully check you have an identifier and colon in _each_ relevant column. This error suggests you *only* have the expression `iif(isnull([NeedUpdateQ]),[SKUP],[NeedUpdateQ])` in the cell without a colon separated name and hence is treated as a column alias and not calculation.

Comment: @Parfait I made sure the formatting for every column is [Table].[Column], with a period inbetween the Table / Column name. What do you mean colon separated? I'm not sure I'm familiar with where the colon needs to go in this syntax.

Comment: In Design view, for expressions, you need a column alias in the format: `Name : Expression` . What you posted should have worked: `SKU_DESC: IIF( ISNULL( [NeedUpdateQ].[SKU_DESC] ) , [SKUP].[SKU_DESC] , [NeedUpdateQ].[SKU_DESC] )`. So I am thinking you mistyped on some other column. Please post the SQL of your query under SQL view.

Comment: @Parfait Apologies for the delayed responses, been a busy day haha. Unfortunately, no luck even while using just the SKU_DESC to test it... I would post the SQL of my query, but because I have been entering it in Design View and it is not proper syntax, it won't let me view the SQL view. I tried using the code provided by Gustav below (the NZ(<val>,<val if null>)), but it isn't working either. Still the exact same syntax I used above, I even tried replacing the "." between table+column name with a "!" to see if it would help, and tried using the expression builder with no luck...

Comment: @Parfait Do you know how I would format this syntax within the SQL view? I would probably rather try that, but I'm not sure how this type of conditional field would even be displayed in SQL, as I'm still learning a lot about SQL

Comment: I tested the syntax in a new blank Select query, and it worked, however once I adjusted the Select Query to an Update Query, it no longer works. Any idea how I can adjust for an Update query? I'm thinking I'll need to make a query where I use these Nz() expressions, then make an Update query from that, to the SKUP table.

Answer (score 1):

Try either of these:

```
SKU_DESC: IIF([NeedUpdateQ].[SKU_DESC] Is Null, [SKUP].[SKU_DESC], [NeedUpdateQ].[SKU_DESC])

SKU_DESC: Nz([NeedUpdateQ].[SKU_DESC], [SKUP].[SKU_DESC])
```

Comment: For current and future readers, `ISNULL()` should still work being valid in Access SQL. OP may have mistyped on at least one of the *every single column* calculation.